# Laravel Data Structure

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, polymorphism, relational-database

Wondering if I could get your thoughts/experience on the following situation? Please let me know if I can clarify any of the information below.

### Problem

I need to interact with Users and Companies, retrieve, filter/sort, and paginate into an integrated html table.

**Relationship structure:** `user` `hasMany()` `company` and `company` `belongsTo()` `user`.

**Clarification:** Only a `user` can log in. A `company` can not log in.

---

### Potential Solutions (as I can see)

#### Polymorphism

Using a `networkable` model/table, relate the `users` and `companies` tables through a `morphTo()` relationship called "displayable()". Retrieval of the merged tables would be done through `Networkable::with('displayable')->get()`.

**Pluses**

1) Database maintains clean separation of `users` and `companies`.

**Trade-offs**

1) Requires maintaining the relationship every time a `user` or `company` is created/deleted

2) Complicates typical eloquent functions since `user` and `company` details would be retrieved via relationship or distant relationship

---

#### Single Table

Store `companies` in the `users` table and treat them as a different entity, even though they are stored in the same table.

**Pluses**

1) Filtering would be pretty natural, and likely faster, since we would be dealing with a single table, and minimal complicated joins.

**Trade-offs**

1) Breaking [Second Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) by adding extra columns in the `users` table, usable only to the "company" type of user.

2) Not all records in the `users` table would actually be users. Confusing? Yes. Certain records in the `users` table would be `companies`, which would have different column information than `users`. `companies` would likely have a boolean called `is_company` or something similar to differentiate between a `company` record and a `user` record.

3) Would require a relationship joining a `user` to the `users` table itself. That way a user could "own" a `company`.

4) Would need to restrict logging in as a `company` since that isn't the intent of a `company`.

---

What do you think? Is one of these options better than the other? Am I missing another solution? Thank you!

---

[image: Desired output]

Comment: A bit confused with what you want displaying? One user with a list of all of it's companies in one cell OR For every company the user is duplicated?

Comment: And I can definitely confirm that un-normalising your database would be a dumb move ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response David! My end goal is to have a table that lists out Users and Companies together. I'm not worried about displaying the relationship between users and companies, but instead treat them similar for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in the https://larachat.slack.com . use a SQL UNION and / or an SQL VIEW to bring them together and have one queryable view.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp
and / or
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

The main credits go to Joseph Silber.

```
$networkable = DB::table('users')->union(DB::table('companies'))->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to follow up here!